# Why is my NSOperationQueue running on main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, parse-platform

I have set up an operation queue:

```
func initialiseOperationQueue(){
    self.operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    self.operationQueue.name = "General queue"
    self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2

}
```

Then I added an operation to my queue

```
let op = HPSyncDataOperation(type: HPSyncDataOperationType.OnlineRecord, delegate: self, date: self.latestLastUpdateAt)
self.operationQueue.addOperation(op)
```

It is basically using Parse framework to asynchronously download some record data online. Its implementation looks like the following:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("recordPosts", withParameters: param, block: { (objects:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
   if error == nil {
       let dataObjects = objects as [PFObject]

       //TROUBLE HERE:
       for object in dataObjects {
            object.pinWithName("Received Posts")
       }
       //abcdefg
   }
})
```

But in execution, when `object.pinWithName("Received Posts")` is run, it invokes

`Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.`

Should an operation be run on a separate thread? So `pinWithName`, regardless of its sync or async, should be run on a separate thread as well?

Please help! Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operation will be run on a background thread, but all it's doing is starting another asynchronous process (`PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground`) which will start another thread. When that other process is complete it calls the completion block on the main thread.

So, in this case your operation and queue are doing basically nothing, and really you should be taking the result of the call to `PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground` (i.e. `objects`) and processing that on a background thread if it's likely to be time consuming.

Comment: Yes, what I did then is I used dispatch_async to create another thread inside the completion block. I still wanted to use NSOperation because there are all other types of downloading on file. I want to keep the code consistent. Is it a good practice?

Comment: Yes, that sounds just fine :-)